# thumbnail images don't show when building an ionic 3.20.0 app on android

Tags: android, build, ionic3

My app works fine in the browser. When I run "ionic cordova run android --device" the app still works fine, only the thumbnail images in a list of links don't show. I tried pngs and jpegs.
The link list is in the HomePage from where I reference the imgs as

```
export class HomePage {
    pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, img: string}>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Sierpinskidrüegg', component: SierpPage, img: "../../assets/imgs/sierp1.jpeg"},
  { title: 'Es Angers Sierpinskidrüegg', component: Sierp2Page, img: '../../assets/imgs/sierp2.jpeg'},
  { title: 'Lorenzattraktor', component: LorenzPage, img: '../../assets/imgs/lorenz.jpeg'}];
```

The HTML:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img [src]="p.img">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2>{{p.title}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

As I said, in the browser, all is what I expect. I'm not able to load them on my Huawei.
I even don't know with what keyword I should search for an answer.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Need to change `page` array `img`**

```
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Sierpinskidrüegg', component: SierpPage, img: "assets/imgs/sierp1.jpeg"},
  { title: 'Es Angers Sierpinskidrüegg', component: Sierp2Page, img: 'assets/imgs/sierp2.jpeg'},
  { title: 'Lorenzattraktor', component: LorenzPage, img: 'assets/imgs/lorenz.jpeg'}];
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks Utpaul

Comment: A further question: Does this also work when I place images  at other locations, maybe not even in the project folder?

Comment: welcome @xaemue . Yes its can be achieve but its work only browser not working on device....